# Unity Alternative for Ubuntu 17.10 and after that

Tags: unity, gnome

I might be the only one but I have to say that I am a huge fan of Unity Desktop. I have been using it since I started to use Linux.

So now Canonical has officially decided to drop Unity in favor of Gnome so what alternatives do I have? I already tried KDE and Gnome but there might be an alternative of Unity itself continued the development by the community?

Comment: Unity will continue. Unity will be in the Universe repos, just an apt away. If there is enough community interest, Unity could be resurrected as a community-based Flavor, just like Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, and the rest.

Comment: @user535733 Yes, I needed to know if any projects as huge as Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc. with active development exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked about "community", well...

look like there is a fork of unity 8 named "yunit" here is their [github repo](https://github.com/yunit-io/yunit):

> This is a fork of Canonical's Unity 8 repository as of April 5, 2017. Following Mark Shuttleworth's announcement to abandon Unity 8 development, we are planning to continue working with the project.

website: yunit.io

---

There is another project named "[Enjade](https://enjade-project.github.io/)" (Now being called "Artemis" I guess):

> The Artemis Project aims to bring the best environments to continue the venerable Unity 7 desktop in the modern Linux space. With an open, friendly community and a willingness to make the Linux desktop more friendly, the Unity legacy will live on while bringing new innovations to the table.
>
> It's going to be a plasma based environment that aims to bring Unity experience while getting new features continuously.

---

You can also make gnome shell to look like unity:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/make-gnome-shell-look-feel-like-unity

However I prefer myself to use a simple highly customizable Window manager instead of DE or at least a lightweight DE like xfce, it's been years that I'm using OpenBox so it never was a big deal for me in first place.